# QGIS Server GetCapabilities does not show map layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I install QGIS2.14 and QGIS Server on CentOS7.8. I make a map project with QGIS, then I put the qgs project into `/var/www/wms`, but when I access the GetCapabilities url through browser, but there is no layer info. What should I do?[image][image]

Comment: Please specify your Web server and version, your URL, and, if necessary, how you make your QGS file. Plus, I'd also like to know why you still use QGIS 2.14(!) when QGIS 3.14.16 has been out for quite some time...

Comment: QGIS Server version2.14.9

Comment: I open the qgis, and create a new project, then I add a local raster layer file to the project, the layer I renamed 'world_layer', next I open the project properties and edit, last I save the project as world.qgs. I put the world.qgs in /var/www/wms/, and type 'local/wms/world?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities'.

Comment: Have you configured your Apache server well according to instructions on https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#serve-a-project ?

Comment: Yes. When I use world.qgs that qgis provided, the GetCapabilities show all layers.

Comment: I install LinuxMint and qgis3.10 before，it works fine. But we have a soft that only supported on centos.